# Redirected input via STDIN is not functioning as expected

Tags: perl, io-redirection

I wrote some code where I thought I was testing for whether there was STDIN.  But the code worked contrary to what I was expecting.

Here's the code I wrote, I've called it `zit`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';

my @a = @ARGV ? @ARGV : "EMPTY";
printf "  command line arguments: \"%s\" as expected\n", @a;
if ( -t STDIN )
  {
    print "  ( -t STDIN ) returns TRUE\n";
  }
else
  {
    print "  ( -t STDIN ) returns FALSE\n";
    print "  But, I can iterate over <STDIN>!  Huh?? Behold:\n";
  }
```

Here's what I thought:

- `zit <(echo a;echo b)` would result in `( -t STDIN )` being `FALSE`.
- `zit < <(echo a;echo b)` would result in`( -t STDIN )` being `TRUE`.

So, to try to figure out what might be going on, I modified the `if-then` code by adding a `while` loop (based upon my understanding, I put it where I thought it should create problems).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';

my @a = @ARGV ? @ARGV : "EMPTY";
printf "  command line arguments: \"%s\" as expected\n", @a;

if ( -t STDIN )
  {
    print "  ( -t STDIN ) returns TRUE\n";
  }
else
  {
    print "  ( -t STDIN ) returns FALSE\n";
    print "  But, I can iterate over <STDIN>!  Huh?? Behold:\n";
    while ( <STDIN> )
      {
        print ">> $_";
      }
  }
```

Here's the output from this code

`zit <(echo a;echo b)` has the following output

```
  command line arguments: "/dev/fd/63" as expected
  ( -t STDIN ) returns TRUE
```

`zit < <(echo a;echo b)` has the following output

```
  command line arguments: "EMPTY" as expected
  ( -t STDIN ) returns FALSE
  But, I can iterate over <STDIN>!  Huh?? Behold:
>> a
>> b
```

I'm really confused by this.  This is not behaving as I thought things should.  If `( -t STDIN )` is false, why does the `while` loop work?

Could someone explain what's happening here?

I've re-edited this post from before to be a bit less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict 'vars';
```

Why are you doing this? You should really just `use strict;` and enable all three strictures, not just `vars`. You should also `use warnings;`.

---

If you check [`perldoc -f -t`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/-t), you'll see that the documentation says:

> `-t  Filehandle is opened to a tty.`

In other words, it's not testing whether there is a STDIN (there always is a STDIN (unless your parent process was naughty and closed it before starting you)), but whether STDIN refers to a terminal (the abbreviation "tty" originally referred to a [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter), but the name kind of stuck when they were replaced by [text terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) and later [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) such as xterm). In C terms, it corresponds to a call to [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

In your first example, you have `zit <(echo a;echo b)`. The `<( ... )` notation makes bash run the specified command with its STDOUT redirected to a pipe. It then substitutes `<( ... )` by a filename that refers to (the read end of) the pipe.

Specifically, it runs `zit /dev/fd/63` (where file descriptor 63 refers to the read end of a pipe whose write end is fed by `echo a; echo b`). Nothing happens to STDIN, so `zit` inherits its standard streams from the shell, so STDIN refers to a terminal, which is why `-t STDIN` returns true.

In your second example, you have `zit < <(echo a;echo b)`. This is very similar, but now the resulting command is `zit < /dev/fd/63`. The `< FILE` notation tells the shell to open the specified file for reading and redirect STDIN to it.

Thus it runs `zit` (without any command line arguments) with STDIN connected to a pipe (whose other end is fed by `echo a; echo b`). This is effectively the same as `( echo a; echo b ) | zit`. Here zit's STDIN refers to a pipe, not a terminal, so `-t STDIN` returns false. You can still read from it, of course: Most things you can read from are not terminals, such as plain files, pipes, or sockets.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  First matter:  from what you're saying, it sounds like I should be testing `( -p STDIN )`, which would make my code more readable and logical.

Comment: Thanks for the other comments about `use strict` and so forth.

Comment: @A.Ellett Well, what are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to know whether your STDIN is interactive (with a user typing into it) or not? If so, you want `-t STDIN` but with your expectations flipped around. :-)

Comment: I originally just wanted perl to rewrite the output of other commands into something more readable.  That brought up a bag of worms about topics for which I don't have much of a firm grasp:  namely pipes, redirection, etc.  So, short answer is, no interactive user input for this particular application.